# Why message property return Null in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties, string-externalization

Im working on a project where i want to externalize **message. properties** file. So that operation team can change according to the requirement.

For that i wrote a configuration class like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"lk.ideahub.symphony.modules", "lk.ideahub.symphony.product"})
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:messages.properties"})})
public class MessageConfig {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        log.info("Message properties loading into the project");
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

In message properties

```
axipay.failure.account.already.exist=Sorry, the biller account number is already added.
```

In my class

```
public Payee myPayees{

//Asking the property into a variable 
private static final String PAYEE_ACCOUNT_ALREADY_EXIST = "axipay.failure.account.already.exist";

@Autowired
Environment environment;

public void myMethod(){
 String message = getEnvironment().getProperty(PAYEE_ACCOUNT_ALREADY_EXIST);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use MessageSource Bean provided by spring 
   https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
//use this method to get message
public String getMessage(){        
return messageSource.getMessage("axipay.failure.account.already.exist", null, new Locale("en"));
}
```